# Can I use wildcards to compare strings?

Tags: delphi, wildcard, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a set of files:

```
001.txt
001a.txt
002.txt 
002a.txt
...
```

I am trying to use the following code to exclude items ending with `a`, such as `001a.txt`

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.FindFiles(StartDir, FileMask: STRING);
VAR
  sr: TSearchRec;
  IsFound: Boolean;
BEGIN
  IsFound := FindFirst(StartDir + FileMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, sr) = 0;
  WHILE IsFound DO
  BEGIN    
    if sr.Name <> '*a.*' then
      gFiles.add(StartDir + sr.Name);

    IsFound := FindNext(sr) = 0;
  END;
  FindClose(sr);
END;
```

The `FileMask` being passed to this procedure is `'*.*'` to include all files.

However the above returns all files.

So my question is how do I exclude those files from the search?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi offers unit `System.Masks` for that. The suitable function here is [MatchesMask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask):

```
if MatchesMask(sr.Name, '*a.*') then
```

Comment: I have used this but inverted it to exclude files from the list.

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed the _to exclude_ part.